# When are web components compatible according to the semver specification?

Tags: polymer-1.0, web-component, jspm, semantic-versioning

Theoretically speaking I'm trying to figure out when a web component linter reading package.json for [JSPM](http://jspm.io/) web component dependencies can determine whether a web component dependency graph can be constructed without having any duplicate web components based on the [Semver Guidelines](http://semver.org/).

I'll just assume we are only talking about dependencies that are compatible.  For example all dependencies list Polymer 1.0^ as a peer dependency.

IIUC all dependencies that don't have major version breaks are compatible.  So for example if one component lists `paper-input:1.3.0^` and another lists `paper-input:1.5.0^` then JSPM can just install the latest version of `paper-input` below `2.0.0`, and the components that require it will use that one version.  On the other hand if there's a component that requires `paper-input:3.4.0^` then the linter can report that there's a transitive dependency that will require having duplicate components.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

You are not missing anything. If all your dependencies follow semantic versioning properly you should be safe following this logic.

Whenever there is a breaking change the major version should be bumped. Any change to either a minor or patch version should still keep the package totally backwards compatible with versions that have a lower precedence and belong to the same major version.